# What is the correct syntax of JavaScript Factory Function? JavaScript Factory Function Syntax confusion

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, factory

Both function getMyCar1 & getMyCar2 has same result but which one is the correct way of doing?

getMycar2: Why value have to use instead of key? key:value (carBrand:brand).

```
function selectCar(brand, model, color){
    return{
        carBrand: brand,
        carModel: model,
        carColor: color, 

        getMyCar1: function(){
            return this.carBrand + " " + this.carModel + " " + this.carColor;  
         //It is said that no need this key word with factory function 
         //but without this key word not working, why?

        },

        getMyCar2: function(){ 
           return brand + " " + model + " " + color;  
           //NotWorking: return carBrand + carModel + carColor
        }
    };
}
```

`let bmw = selectCar("bmw", "X6", "White");`
`console.log("My Car Model is: " + bmw.getMyCar1());`

`let audi = selectCar("Audi", "A8", "Red");`
`console.log("My Car Model is: " + audi.getMyCar2());`

Comment: "*It is said that no need this key word with factory function*" who said that? And in what context? You definitely need `this` is you want to reference something from the object. You don't need it in other cases. A blanket statement omits a lot of details.

Comment: Try `bmw.carColor = "black"`, and then try calling both functions again…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: bmw.carColor = "black";
audi.carColor = "yellow";
console.log("My Car Model is: " + bmw.getMyCar1());
console.log("My Car Model is: " + audi.getMyCar2());  bmw car color changed to black but audi car color NOT CHANGED  to yellow. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. i.e.,
If you want that function to return the current state of a car instance, you have **getMycar1** function:
Example:

```
let bmw = selectCar("bmw", "X6", "White"); 
bmw.carColor= "black"
console.log("My Car Model is: " + bmw.getMyCar2());
```

Result is:

> My Car Model is: bmw X6 black

Here we changed car color and is reflected in the function.

on the other hand if you want a method to show initial state of car, **getMyCar2** function is for you as it does change car attributes.

```
let audi = selectCar("Audi", "A8", "Red");
audi.carColor = 'black'
console.log("My Car Model is: " + audi.getMyCar2());
```

> My Car Model is: Audi A8 Red

**getMyCar2** function uses parameters passed to the function as values and so doesnt change its output when any attribute is changed in a car instance